# float:left issue across browsers

Tags: css-float

I'm trying to align the 'hot picks' tab so it sits beside the slideshow at my site http://www.loveartmusicbaby.com which works in Firefox with the float: left code as posted below. But how can I get it to work also on Chrome and IE? :/

```
<img src="http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/4756/tabcv.png" alt="art music fashion" style="float: left;" /><div id="s3slider"><ul id="s3sliderContent">

<li class="s3sliderImage"><a href="http://lovetest22.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/as-beth-dittos-collaboration-with-m.html#more"><img style="width:569px;height:341px;" src="http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/2513/wasex.jpg" /><span>Why we <font color="ff00ae">love </font> fashion designer, Hayley Scanlan</span></a></li>

<li class="s3sliderImage"><a href="YOUR-LINK-HERE"><img style="width:569px;height:341px;" src="http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/1678/dollnp.jpg" /><span> The First Ladies of music feat. <font color="ff00ae">Kimbra </font> </span></a></li>

<li class="s3sliderImage"><a href="YOUR-LINK-HERE"><img style="width:569px;height:341px;" src="http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/4583/fdaw.jpg" /><span>Meet <font color="ff00ae">Helen Green</font>, the coolest Little Monster around. </span></a></li>

<li class="s3sliderImage"><a href="YOUR-LINK-HERE"><img style="width:569px;height:341px;" src="http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/7456/saudin.jpg" /><span> Cute as <font color="ff00ae">candy:</font> The Saudi fashion designer causing a stir</span></a></li>

<li class="s3sliderImage"><a href="YOUR-LINK-HERE"><img style="width:550px;height:200px;" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_4HKUHirY_2U/S9aKtosfYNI/AAAAAAAAA-o/GTCV0pnicVk/s1600/call+of+duty-11.jpg" /><span>Call Of Duty 4 : Get Here</span></a></li>

</ul></div>

<div class='clear'></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#s3slider` simply does not fit to width of the parent. Try

```
#s3slider {
     width:560px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Changing the width doesn't appear to resolve the problem though.

Comment: @user1624737, try `560px` just to check. The problem is here. It only can be wrong number

Comment: Perfect, sorted. Not quite a float:left issue after all then. Many thanks!